# Do I need a service for exposing every app running in a pod?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I'm planning to build a website to host static files. Users will upload their files and I deploy bunch of deployments with `nginx` images on those to a Kubernetes node. My main goal is for some point, users will deploy their apps to a subdomain like `my-blog-app.mysite.com`. After some time users can use custom domains.

I understand that when I deploy an nginx image on a pod, I have to create a service to expose port 80 (or 443) to the internet via load balancer.

I also read about `Ingress`, looks like what I need but I don't think I understand that concept.

My question is, for example if I have 500 nginx pods running (each is a different website), do I need a service for every pod in that node (in this case 500 services)?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting.

With this type of Ingress, you route the traffic to the different nginx instances, based on the Host header, which perfectly matches your use-case.

In any case, yes, assuming your current architecture you need to have a service for each pod. Haven't you considered a different approach? Like having a general listener (nginx instances) and get the correct content based on authorization or something?

Comment: That looks like what I wanted. But I have one more question. If I have for example 100 deployments running, then yaml file for Ingress will be too long, and every time I deploy another deployment, I need to change my yaml file and apply that. Isn't it a bit overwhelming? Or Is there a solution for that?

Comment: @BatınEvirgen that's why I said that probably you can re-engineer this in a different way.